# How to find records in a table that are related to all the records in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have three tables:

- Foo
- Bar
- FooBar

FooBar is a relation table that contains collection of `Foo`s and `Bar`s that are related to one another, it has only two columns (FooId, BarId).

My code so far for getting all the `Foo` that relate to all the `Bar`s out:

```
select 
    f.*
from 
    Foo f
where
    f.FooId IN 
         (
        SELECT fb.FooId
        FROM FooBar fb
        GROUP BY fb.FooId
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bar)
         )
```

There has to be more efficient way to write this. I could put total number of `Bar`s in a SQL variable outside of outer select so it doesn't execute every time, but that's the only optimization that I can think of so far.

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of this program is? I read the title, and it vaguely reminded me of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877178/using-god-to-monitor-unicorn-start-exited-with-non-zero-code-1

Comment: Maybe it's worth to change subject area?

Comment: Actually your query gives pretty good execution plan, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @IDWMaster - Actual problem I have can be simplified to this, I just assumed this title would get me more views and thus answers than title with releases and customers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will return all the `Foo` that are related to all the `Bar`.  It uses the `exists` operator:

```
select *
from @Foo f
where not exists(
    select 1
    from @Bar b
    left join @FooBar fb on fb.BarID = b.ID and fb.FooID = f.ID
    where fb.FooID is null
)
```

Sample data:

```
declare @FooBar table(BarID int, FooID int)
insert @FooBar values(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (1,2), (2,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3)

declare @Bar table(ID int)
insert @Bar values(1), (2), (3)

declare @Foo table(ID int)
insert @Foo values(1), (2), (3)
```

Comment: that solves the solution of getting "a girl record" if one exists, but what about the case when you want all matching girl records?

Comment: @polishchuk thanks for comment but for large number of data (BoyGirl count over 3.000.000) this is very slow (ex. time: 43 sec)

Comment: @Matija The `where bg.GirlID is null` requires a Filter operation thats why. What is the time on your original query? If its bad maybe you should consider putting your inner query (needs some rearranging) in an indexed view.

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo, Subject area changed? :-)

Comment: Yeah, I reopened and then changed the title to make it more clear, but then the question just looked weird so I went ahead and edited it to be more generic and then edited your post to match