# Custom "action" with God?

Tags: ruby, unicorn, god

We actually use God in our development environment, as well as in production, simply because it makes managing unicorn/resque etc simpler.

I've just scaled down our default unicorn config to a single worker in dev, as *most* of the time this is enough.  However, I've added shell scripts wrapping the commands:

```
# Add an extra unicorn worker
kill -TTIN `cat /path/to/unicorn.pid`

# Remove a unicorn worker
kill -TTOU `cat /path/to/unicorn.pid`
```

Rather than starting/stopping/restarting unicorn with god, but adding new workers through an ad-hoc shell script, is there a way to have God support a couple of custom commands, like:

```
god incr unicorn

god decr unicorn
```

I looked in the documentation and found nothing, but it feels like something it would probably 'unofficially' be able to do.

Comment: [Insert hopefully tasteful joke about deities and mythological animals here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877178/using-god-to-monitor-unicorn-start-exited-with-non-zero-code-1)

Comment: Ruby hipsters gotta love silly gem names :) One day somebody will make a gem called something like 'penis', and it will actually be useful, we'll all end up having to just deal with it, keeping a straight face.

Comment: Note to ruby hipsters: pick names that are easier to google.

Comment: @ergosys Note to self: come up with some names that are hard to google.